# Suppress line object in details section based on conditions

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using Crystal Report 2008. I've a report result which is included more then 1 page and 1 group. Sample result as below:

Page 1:

<< Group Header >> # Item No. Price 

<< Group Header >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** 

<< Details a >> 1 ItemA001 $1,000 

<< Details a >> 2 ItemA002 $1,000

<< Details a >> 3 ItemA003 $2,000

<< Group Footer >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

<< Group Footer >> Total: $4,000

Page 2:

<< Group Header >> # Item No. Price

<< Group Header >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

<< Details a >> 1 ItemB001 $2,000 

<< Details a >> 2 ItemB002 $1,500

<< Details a >> 3 ItemB003 $2,000

<< Group Footer >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** 

<< Group Footer >> Total: $5,500

Now I want to insert a line between every row as below:

(As I know user can't set conditions for line object to suppress, so I add the line in details b)

Page 1:

<< Group Header >> # Item No. a Price 

<< Group Header >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

<< Details a >> 1 ItemA001 $1,000 

<< Details b >> ----------------- 

<< Details a >> 2 ItemA002 $1,000

<< Details b >> -----------------

<< Details a >> 3 ItemA003 $2,000

<< Details b >> **----------------- How to suppress?**

<< Group Footer >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** 

<< Group Footer >> Total: $4,000

Page 2:

<< Group Header >> # Item No. Price

<< Group Header >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

<< Details a >> 1 ItemA001 $1,000 

<< Details b >> ----------------- 

<< Details a >> 2 ItemA002 $1,000

<< Details b >> -----------------

<< Details a >> 3 ItemA003 $2,000

<< Details b >>**----------------- How to suppress?**

<< Group Footer >> ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** 

<< Group Footer >> Total: $5,500

I've tried suppress if "RecordNumber >= Count({ItemNo.})" but RecordNumber didn't reset for second page so all details b will be suppress in page 2.

How can I set conditions to suppress details b for last record in each group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below solution.

Create a running total  for the field in detail section and running total should be like this.

```
1. Field to summarize should be Database Field, Type of summary should be "Count".

2. Evaluate for each record.

3. Reset for change of Group
```

Now you got the count of records in that group.

1. To supress the line for last record go to the Details b supress formula editor and give below code. Take the count of records of the filed in detail section using insert summary

   `IF (Count (Filed, Group})=Running total)
   then true
   else false`

Once the count(it gives one value count of records) equals to running total value the line will be supressed.

This is tested code and working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Suppress 'Details B'  section with this rule:

```
onlastrecord or next(table.groupfield)<>table.groupfield
```

Comment: Nice and simple - love it!